# How to chain knowrob and rosjava workspaces

Tags: ros, knowrob, rosjava, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a succesfull installation `Indigo` and `rosjava` in `Ubuntu` 14.04 according to [this](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source) and [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/indigo/Installation) instructions I got following error when I was making `KnowRob` from sources:

```
CMake Error at /home/al/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "rosjava_build_tools" with any of the following names:

    rosjava_build_toolsConfig.cmake
    rosjava_build_tools-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rosjava_build_tools" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "rosjava_build_tools_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "rosjava_build_tools" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/knowrob_common/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/knowrob_common/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'knowrob_common': 
  Command '/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosprolog/env.sh cmake /home/al/ros_catkin_ws/src/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_common -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/knowrob_common -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -G Unix Makefiles' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I think it occures because workspaces is not chained. There is a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) that describes how to chain workspaces, but after a default installation (according to mentioned tutorials) we have the following directories: `~/ros_catkin_ws` and `~/rosjava`. It's not clear how to chain them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201616/how-to-chain-knowrob-and-rosjava-workspaces/) by [Alexey Reshetnyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/21462/alexey-reshetnyak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces) explains the necessary steps: The key is which setup.bash you have sourced when running catkin_make. The first time (Sec. 3.3) you have sourced the one in /opt/ros/indigo/..., then you build the first workspace (in your case containing the rosjava repositories, let's assume it's at ~/rosjava), then you create another directory, call catkin_init_workspace, source the setup.bash from your rosjava workspace (~/rosjava/devel/setup.bash), and then run catkin_make on that workspace again. In the end, you have to source the setup.bash from your custom workspace (e.g. ~/custom_pkgs/devel/setup.bash) since only that contains all packages, the ones in /opt/ros, the ones in ~/rosjava, and the ones in ~/custom_pksgs.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alexey Reshetnyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/21462/alexey-reshetnyak/) on 2015-01-26**:
It helped. But I didn't have `/opt/ros` directory when I built `Indigo` from sources. So I gave up. I installed `Indigo` through `apt-get`. Directory `/opt/ros` appeared in the my system. Then I installed `rosjava` and `KnowRob` from sources, the key point was to `source` right `setup.bash`. Thanks!

**Comment by [kenari](https://answers.ros.org/users/21650/kenari/) on 2015-02-16**:
Alexey, thanks for sharing. Could you please explain a bit more specifically how to source  the right setup.bash?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello kenari,
here the steps that worked for my system: `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`, `Indigo`:

```
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace
cd ~/catkin_ws/
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
rosdep update
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
rosws init
wstool merge https://raw.github.com/knowrob/knowrob/indigo-devel/rosinstall/knowrob-tutorial.rosinstall
wstool update
rosdep install --ignore-src knowrob
cd ~/catkin_ws
source /home/al/rosjava/devel/setup.bash
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Alexey Reshetnyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/21462/alexey-reshetnyak/) with karma: 17 on 2015-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [toddcpierce](https://answers.ros.org/users/25497/toddcpierce/) on 2016-08-22**:
Hi All,

I´ve been trying to install knowrob for weeks, but I get the rosjava_build_tools error.  There doesn´t appear to be a way to install rosjava on kinetic.  Any ideas how to get knowrob working without rosjava?  Or, at least be able to communicate with prolog from lisp?

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2016-08-22**:
You can try to manually build individual packages along the dependency chain. rosjava seems to ignore the catkin dependencies in CMakeLists and package.xml. I've just compiled knowrob again and it worked when building first knowrob_common, then knowrob_srdl, then knowrob_mongo and others.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2016-08-22**:
catkin_make --pkg knowrob_common etc

**Comment by [toddcpierce](https://answers.ros.org/users/25497/toddcpierce/) on 2016-08-24**:
I lilke the suggestions on how to do all of this stuff on Indigo and older versions of Linux, but does anybody have any idea how to install ROSJava on Kinetic on 16.04?  I mean, any instructions I follow, even installing from source, result in files not existing out there in the cloud.